# How do I construct a multibit quantum operator for non-consecutive bits?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, quantum-computation

I understand (I think) that I can construct a gate operating on $n$ bits for a an $m>n$ $m$-bit system where the bits on which the gate operates are "adjacent" at positions $p+1$ through $p+n$ from the corresponding gate $G_n$ that operates on a $n$-bit system as

$$I^{\otimes p}\otimes G_n\otimes I^{\otimes (m-n-p)}$$

but it's not clear to me how to do this of the affected bits are at arbitrary positions in the operand.

For example how would I construct a CNOT gate operating on the 3rd and 7th bits of an 8 bit system, or a CCNOT gate operating on the 2nd, 5th and 8th?

Is there a general expression, like the one above for accomplishing this that I'm just missing, or is the procedure more involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CNOT gate over a two-bit system can be written as 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \otimes I + \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \otimes \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
where the first bit is used as the controller for the second.

For a CNOT gate in which the 3rd bit is used as a controller for the 7th, we could write
$$
G = I^{\otimes 2} \otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \otimes I^{\otimes 3} \otimes I \otimes I \\
+ 
I^{\otimes 2} \otimes \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \otimes I^{\otimes 3} \otimes \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} \otimes I
$$
Perhaps now it is clear how this should be done in general.

---

Taking $M$ as above, we can express the CCNOT gate over a 3-bit system as
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \otimes I^{\otimes 2} + \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \otimes M
$$
Distributing this tensor product, we can write the gate as
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \otimes I^{\otimes 2}
+ \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0&0} \otimes I
+ \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \otimes \pmatrix{0 & 0\\0 & 1} \otimes \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
Now, we apply the same trick.  In other words, we insert an $I$ for the slots corresponding to bits that are left alone.

Comment: Yes but the key step is sorting out what "acting on a single qbit" means in general. That's not clear; to me at least. What is C for CNOT, or CCNOT, for example?

Comment: Ah, I actually wasn't totally clear on what a CNOT gate does.  I'll have to fix my answer.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: I see what this is doing for the CNOT case, but it's not clear to me how this extends to the [CCNOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) case (where 3 bits are involved).

Comment: Updated my post.  Again, see my latest edit.

Comment: Got it (at least for these). I think I need to study Kronecker factorization of matrices a bit.

Comment: But it seems like sorting out how to break up the matrix into chunks a lot on the structure of the matrix being factored. Here for example the last chunk has to be 2x2 ("addressed") as the 2x2 chuck in the bottom right of CCNOT with $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 &0\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{matrix} 0 &0\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$, while we can get away with addressing the larger, 4x4 first chunk with just $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 &0\\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ because that chunk factors easily into two 2x2s.

Comment: @orome it's not as bad as it seems.  We can always break up the matrix as
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D} = \\
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \otimes A + 
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} \otimes B + 
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0} \otimes C + 
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \otimes D
$$

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with that. (I'm trying to write some code to apply arbitrary n-bit operators to bits in arbitrary positions in a state.)

Comment: @orome Sounds like an interesting project.  Hope that goes well